# Statement about Cholov Yisroel following general expectations

Tags: halacha, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

In this article in [Kosher Today](http://www.koshertoday.com/government-definition-milk-raises-new-questions-kashrus-officials/) speaking about the potential for the FDA to allow non-Kosher milk to be labeled as plain milk quotes an unnamed Kashrus Organization official as saying that milk as of now can still be regarded as under the Heter of Rav Moshe Feinstein. The article says:

> Other kashrus officials reached by KosherToday also expressed the hope that the FDA would narrow the definition of milk to cows and goats, but did not see any immediate problem with the kosher status of dairy products. One official said simply: “Ask any American where milk comes from and they will tell you from a cow.”

Now, I recognize that this is a media article and thus could just as likely get what the relevant official said wrong, but is there *any* Halachic basis for the idea that because the non-Jewish population expects their milk to be from a cow it can be presumed to actually be from a cow?

Comment: Wow! Seems like an odd comparison to me. Perhaps, there is a halachic rule / precedent being used in this area that states that a common / populace assumption can be used? (Aside - do you know a deaf Chaba"d guy named Yeshoshua Sudakoff?)

Comment: is your question focused on the idea that a halachic standard is based on popular knowledge/behavior or that the populace in question here is made of non-Jews?

Comment: @Danno, well, either way. The fact is "any American" is 98% non-Jewish, so in this case it is being used to justify that the milk must not have an issue of requiring direct supervision of a Jew. Is there a basis for that?

Comment: @DanF, no I don't.

Comment: i call bs until i see some actual sources in that article.

Comment: @Aaron, the law under discussion in the article [is real](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/BillStatus.asp?GA=99&DocTypeID=SB&DocNum=1228&GAID=13&SessionID=88&LegID=87585).

Comment: @ Yishai Apparently i can't understand how laws are written, because to me it sounds like SB1228 is doing the exact opposite of what the Kosher Today article is saying. Because the first amendment to the bill says specifically "Removes milk from hooved mammals other than cows, goats, sheep, or water buffalo from the definition of "milk"." http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/fulltext.asp?DocName=09900SB1228sam001&GA=99&LegID=87585&SessionId=88&SpecSess=0&DocTypeId=SB&DocNum=1228&GAID=13&Session=  so maybe when the article was published the amendment wasn't there yet?

Comment: @Aaron, the Kosher Today article is saying that Illinois tightened the definition of milk ahead of a possible FDA expansion of it. This legislation, indeed as you understood it, is tightening that definition to ensure that camel and horse aren't included. My understanding is the previous, expansive definition would have been overridden by tighter FDA requirements anyway. Helps if you live in Illinois, and the FDA actually follows through.

Answer (score 2):

I think he means something different. This is not an unfounded assumption in the eyes of the populace. His point probably is to say everyone knows it's cows milk, because that is what is normally used. This is an understanding between the retailer and the consumer based on practice. If anyone would deviate, expectations would not be fulfilled which would cause problems, which is why no milk seller will ever put other animals milk in their product, until of course it becomes socially accepted to.

Assuming this, this would be  an explicit law in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah siman 153 where we find an allowance to leave our animals with nonjews when the nonjewish society is not rova them, something which was not allowed in Talmudic times, being that they did do this issur and there is a lifnei iver issue. To clarify, our issur of lifnei iver is now assumed to be non existent due to our relying on their societal practices.

At this point you might argue that that allowance would not help with other issurim which effect us directly. This is not true.

Ramma filling in the rest of the gemara tells us we still shouldn't leave our children with them to be watched as they can still teach the children heresy and get away with it, so we cannot trust them. This is based directly off the gemara and Rashi as brought in the Tur.

We see clearly that there is no distinction made between one type of issur and another. The case of the children is obviously dealing with an issue that will have a result on the Jewish person, and no distinction is made between the two.

The fact is, if they commonly do something that is problematic for us, we cannot rely on them not doing it. Whereas if they don't commonly do something, we can assume they won't.

The Mechaber here mentions a kol shekein to rely on them when the government enforces the allowed practice.
But that is not the basis for the basic rule. The basic halacha is simply a matter of assumptions.

This idea is present in hilchos pas palter as well where we were able to assume there were no nonkosher ingredients added to the bread, back when they didn't normally add other ingredients.

Again, this has nothing to do with believing them, or trusting them. This is our own assumptions made about them.

To end off, I would just like to point out that I know many people who would never eat chalav stam chas vishalom, but regularly use nonjewish child care, whereas I can think of hardly anyone who consumes chalav stam but only uses Jewish childcare.
I'm willing to bet the Ramma would tell people to save money by buying chalav stam and save up to afford the more expensive Jewish childcare.

Comment: But can this be applied to Cholov Yisroel, where you have a specific Gezeras Chachamim not to just rely on the fact that they don't normally add non-Kosher? Even according to the Pri Chodosh he requires the whole town to be pig free. BTW, I think the impact on the budget of Cholov Yisroel is exaggerated, but I agree that non-Jewish childcare is a **much** bigger problem.

Comment: I don't want to answer your question al regel achas, but I think yichud with them was a gezeira too. And the end result of the child care issue is the same end result of all the food related gezeiros according to most opinions that bnoseihen was atu davar acher.

Comment: BTW, if you could source someone actually making this argument l'halacha, I would accept this answer.

Comment: @Yishai how about Rabbi Yosef Karo? Ha ha ha. Just kidding of course. Who uses that for halacha? But seriously folks, see also in Yoreh Deah hilchos klai begadim siman 302 siff 2 Mechaber Ramma & Achronim about assumptions and price vs ease of use vs sustainability. It's also very telling.

Comment: I'm not doubting that such Umdenos are used. I'm questioning their applicability to Cholov Yisroel - especially when not using the Pri Chodosh, but if you found someone paskening today like the Pri Chodosh, that would be a complete answer.

Comment: @Yishai aha. Ok.

Comment: Wait. All you wanted was to know what this Rabbi was thinking. I shouldn't have to prove if he is correct or not should I? If you know about this pri chaddash than that's all you should need.

Comment: As for who rules like this, apparently nobody. The only one of our major accepted achronim who has this siman is chayei adam. See there, especially the little type. But again, I'm confused why this is the only halacha the achronim are not meikel based on times changing. See siman 116 again the mechaber is lenient in the face of the takana not to drink mayim gluyim when there are no snakes.

Comment: Well, you can't know what this Rabbi was thinking, especially since he is anonymous, but if you are answering according to the pri chadash and say so, I think you have a solid answer. I don't know that this is the only Halacha, but see e.g. the Aruch HaShulchan who argues that the Gezeirah of Cholov Yisroel is more than its stated reason, so the nullification of the reason doesn't remove the Gezeirah. Note the Ramo still invalidates milk if you came late - but were expected to walk in at any moment - and nothing but cows in the herd, once there is rov milk like that.

Answer (score 2):

Rav Moshe's psak on "Chalav HaCompanies" is restricted to the U.S. and Canada because of the strictness of the FDA inspections and the laws and procedures involving the farms and the dairy processors. It has nothing to do with "common assumptions" as we see in European countries where such milk is not allowed.

[Rav Moshe Feinstein’s Heter of Cholov Stam Revisited](http://matzav.com/rav-moshe-feinsteins-heter-of-cholov-stam-revisited/)

> Currently, the government inspects all milk farms 2-6 times per year.
>
> Governmental (state) farm inspection protocol specifically includes a
>   provision that only cows are in the farms’ milking parlors and/or
>   cowyard. This provision (formulated in terms of swine) is part of the
>   standard farm inspection form. (See sections of Dairy Farm Inspection
>   Forms below.)
>
> Government inspectors track the intake and output of all milk at
>   dairies. Thus, the source farms are identified by the inspectors, and
>   they must correlate with farms approved by the government.

[In what countries is chalav yisrael not required for milk?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2926/in-what-countries-is-chalav-yisrael-not-required-for-milk) also discusses the matter.

The official definition of **milk** from the FDA is restricted to cows. "goats milk" is restricted to goats. Changing the definition to include any other animal would require publication in the official FDA "Request for Comments" and require specific reference to the percentages of additional ingredients. Even discussions **before** the "request for Comments" is issued must first reach the public and the dairy industry.

see the comment with the link from @Aaron

Thus, according to the FDA, cows milk and goats milk may not be mixed without explicit labeling, much less that of any other animal.

There is a movement by lobbyists to include Aspartame (artificial sweetener) in the definition but people are objecting to that. If they would change to definition to include that of other animals, they will have to first publicize the matter first.

If the FDA is going to change the rules, then they would have to give the source animal on each label. Even if the definition changes, it would not allow "blended" milk from different animals. Thus, "Cows milk" must only be from cows. "goats milk" must only be from goats, etc. As a result, one should not worry about milk from nonkosher animals being sold without a reference to the animal it came from.

Senator Dan Coats letter is dealing with mock milk (such as Soy Milk) rather than milk from other animals. If milk from other animals is mixed in to the milk from a dairy, the dairy can be forced to buy all such adulterated products at the full price of Grade A milk. It is that penalty which Rav Moshe used to allow "Chalav HaCompanies".

[Code of Federal Regulations Revised as of April 1, 2014 PART 131 -- MILK AND CREAM](http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfcfr/CFRSearch.cfm?FR=131.110)

(a) Description. Milk is the lacteal secretion, practically free from colostrum, obtained by the complete milking of one or more healthy cows. Milk that is in final package form for beverage use shall have been pasteurized or ultrapasteurized, and shall contain not less than 8 1/4 percent milk solids not fat and not less than 3 1/4 percent milkfat. Milk may have been adjusted by separating part of the milkfat therefrom, or by adding thereto cream, concentrated milk, dry whole milk, skim milk, concentrated skim milk, or nonfat dry milk. Milk may be homogenized.

Comment: Before these things are put up for official comment they are discussed. That is the stage this is in. Not clear how this information answers the question.

Comment: @Yisha Find some other information about this, because as Rabbi Yitzhak Abadi points out, camel milk is $18 per pint, there's no way they'd mix that into cows milk, it's not cost effective. Someone asked him about this supposed "article" and his reponse was: "lol-definitely gets credit for being original! i have a bridge for sale -YA" http://www.kashrut.org/forum/viewpost.asp?mid=56992&highlight=camel

Comment: @Yishai I added an explanation about how the rules work. Even if they allowed the change they would not be able to sell milk from other animals without specifying which animal it came from.

Comment: @Yishai Another example is horse milk which sells at 20 times the price for cows milk (according to ads for horse milk) They would not mix it into cows milk and hurt their market.

Comment: My question isn't about the FDA rules.

Comment: Or about the likelyhood of economic benefit or other such umdenos. It is about the assetion that everybody means 'cow's milk' when they say milk.

Comment: @Yishai That is what I restricted my answer to. I also pointed out that the truth in labeling laws would require the source animal to be listed on the label and not allow milk from any other animal to be mixed in.

Comment: @Yishai It is also the reason that I gave my answer in terms of law enforcement and not common assumptions.

Comment: @Aaron a couple of times back in yeshiva when having these discussions I pulled out a big bill and offered it to anyone who can brink me a quart of tamei milk. Conversation over:)

Comment: @sabbahillel your answer (read: comment) seems to be aimed at my answer. Notice I hadn't once mentioned Reb Moshe's name. I was working strictly from the Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: @user6591 I did not address your answer. I strictly kept it to Rav Moshe's teshuva and the current situation.

Comment: @sabbahillel It has nothing to do with "common assumptions" seems to me to be addressing my answer. You even put my words in quotation marks.

Comment: @sabbahillel, if your point is that the FDA currently allows only cows milk to be called milk, that isn't my question. My question is about an assertion that even if they didn't, everyone calls only cows milk milk, so it is fine.

Comment: @Yishai My point is not that it is because everyone assumes it is or calls it cows' milk. That is why I bring the quotes about Rav Moshe's psak. It is only because of the the enforcement (or the lack of any other animal from which milk is taken). That is also why there are countries in Europe (I have been told Spain and Italy as examples but cannot verify that) which cannot be trusted even though everyone assumes that all milk is cows' milk.

Comment: @sabbahillel, so basically you are saying that according Rav Moshe's psak, this fact that everyone calls cows milk 'milk' is not the basis. I guess that is fine, it just addresses the answer in a very minor way. I asked is there *any* basis and you are answering at least not according to Rav Moshe.

Comment: BTW, I don't know about what the FDA is or is not considering, but the Illinois legislation [is real](http://www.ilga.gov/legislation/BillStatus.asp?GA=99&DocTypeID=SB&DocNum=1228&GAID=13&SessionID=88&LegID=87585)

Comment: @Yishai According to the information that I have, Rav Moshe's psak is the leniency as to why we are allowed to use stam milk. Thus, if Rav Moshe would not allow it, it would appear that others would not allow it either. However, his psak only applies to the U.S. and Canada. Each country would have its own ruling (such as London Bais Din for example).