# R Moshe Feinstein on Chalav Stam

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, leniencies, moshe-feinstein, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

1. When does R Moshe's heter apply - is **bshaas hadchak** required? If so, what would constitute bshaas hadchak?
2. **Is it a minhag**, or plainly Halachic, to insist on chalav yisroel where it is hardly available (regardless of bshaas hadchak or not)?
3. [deleted]
4. Assuming the law imposes a penalty by fine or prison on mislabelling of food ingredients; it is also unheard of, to have unkosher animals' milk in the vicinity. Do we disregard the possibility that the corporations nevertheless mislabel the milk because it decides that a violation of law is still more economically beneficial than abidance?
5. Assuming the heter applies, would the chalav stam be regarded as of the same status as chalav yisroel?

Thank you!

Comment: http://matzav.com/rav-moshe-feinsteins-heter-of-cholov-stam-revisited/ An interesting article with some relevant points.

Comment: Offhand, I'm not sure the definition of "bshaas hadchak" applies, here. One is not halachically required to have dairy items.

Comment: I believe Rav Moshe's own children are not makpid on chalav yisrael, albeit in the US.

Comment: @Loewian and, I think, Canada, also.

Comment: @DanF why would you assume that shaat hadechak has anything to do with a halakhic requirement?

Comment: You would have to ask a rav who is familiar with Hong Kong and its legal setup. Such a rav would be able to tell you if the milk there falls into the *chalav hacompanies* status that Rav Moshe referred to. There are countries that have such laws on the books but are not sufficiently enforced to rely on and others that are. Your question 5 can be answered *no* because even in the US they do not have the same *status* unless you mean a status of mutar rather than asur.

Comment: @mevaqesh The definition of  "sha'at hadchak" generally means "urgency" - when you have no other choice and you MUST perform a certain mitzvah or halacha. There is no requirement to consume dairy.

Comment: alexandrahakatan, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your questions here! I think there may be too much going on in this post to answer at once, so it may be a good idea to [edit] this down and post additional questions as necessary. I think (1) and (2), general questions about circumstances in which Ch"Y applies, could be one question post. (3), about spiritual consequences, could be a second. I'll come back to (4) in my next comment. (5) is really also a (third) general question: Wherever R' Moshe's leniency applies, does that make the milk the same status as C"Y?

Comment: Regarding (4), specifically about the status of Hong Kong, there are two ways to pose this question that could be answered here: a) Provide as much relevant information about the situation in Hong Kong as you can, and ask for a theoretical analysis *on the basis of whatever information you've provided*, which is more or less what you're getting at here, though I think it could be clearer on the contextual information. b) Ask whether any rabbis have ruled regarding Hong Kong, in particlular, which, if answered, could also produce an answer to [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2926/).

Comment: Finally, regarding what you and those in your community should actually do, in practice, I highly recommend checking with [your local rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146) and not simply following anything you read here, since [Mi Yodeya is not a rabbi](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: One more thing: This is highly related to (2): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31833/chalav-yisrael-milk-stringency-or-binding

Comment: Its intresting to note that the heter works in American due to its laws,however see the Pri Chadash who was before Rav Moshe

Comment: Thanks all. I have edited the question to be general rather than Hong Kong-specific.

Comment: There is no such thing a chalav stam it is either Chalav Yisrael or chalav akum,Rav Moshe calls it chalav hacompaines , chalav akum is assur,so if one allows the milk to be drunk then its considered chalav yisrael,either like the Pri Chadash who hel that if no non kosher milk is around in the city then there is no chalav akum,and then Rav Moshes opinon that if the govt has regulations then its knowing and knowing is like seeing.

Comment: @sabbahillel His teshuva in the Igros Moshe notwithstanding, I believe Rav  Moshe's view as presented and practiced by his children was that he did indeed view American chalav stam as entirely equivalent to chalav yisrael.

Comment: @Loewian I've heard a range of contradictory opinion from various people on whether whether Chalav stam under his heter has the equivalent status of Chalav Yisrael, but no one cited anything. Guess that'd have to be a separate topic of discussion.